# asset compilation css error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.1 and when I run the rake task I get this css error.

```
$ rake assets:precompile
/Users/nnn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby /Users/nnn/dev/personal/demoapp/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "...{padding-bottom": expected "{", was ";0;}#order_deta..."
```

Is there a way to tell rails to ignore the syntax check for css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This failure comes out of the scss process

```
gems/sass-3.1.11/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:926:in `expected'
```

It seems all css files get parsed as scss.

The easy way to turn it off is just to disable sass.

```
group :assets do
  # gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

But if you're actually using it, then that won't work.

Or you could fix your css!